# Statistical Analysis of motion under central force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

My question is very simple. If we were to plot the motion of a particle inside circular walls governed by a central attractive force with perfectly elastic collisions, would the statistics of the velocity and positions of the particle over a very long period of time give any interesting features like maybe waves?

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend reading this, the motion really depneds on the initial conditions of the particle:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem

Comment: Your answer constitutes a "link-only" answer which is not "ideal" in Physics SE. If the link goes dead, the answer will be completely invalidated. It is good practice to at least provide a brief explanation on what the link contains and describe the given solution enough for someone to be able to understand it without reaching the link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/386935)

Comment: I would comment it instead of answering if i could, but i cant, and the answer considers many different cases so i did not include it here. Is that alright?

Comment: I understand that you cannot comment yet, but you'll eventually get enough reputation to do so. I would recommend avoiding "link-only" answers in general (irrespective of reputation) for the aforementioned reason. You could possibly provide at least some insight on the various solutions provided by the link, or at least summarise the content. I won't argue that "link-only" answers do **not** provide any help, so I won't be the one to say whether it is OK or not to leave it as it is, but I mostly care for people here (whether new or experienced users/contributors) the reason of this practice.

Comment: Yep, thanks for letting me know